# REPLACE() CONCAT() & SUBSTR() for inserting one character in between concatenated fields

Tags: mysql, replace, concatenation

I continue to get an **SQL Syntax error**. I tested all fields with prefixes etc and all data is loading OK, but when I trying to use my replace concat, won't stop throwing errors.. Any idea why this would happen?

I also need the white space removed from the nums table.

**Data input format:**
    nums: 21 0440N 0110W 026
    state: CA
    part: AA

**Final results should look like:**
    CA21T0440N0110W026AA (note the white space is also removed.)

```
replace(
           concat(
               b.state,
                   substr(b.nums, 0, 3),
               'T',
                   substr(b.nums, 3),
               b.part
                  )
      ) AS AllInfoConcat,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are the two other parameters for `REPLACE`? This should work:

```
REPLACE(
  CONCAT(b.state, substr(b.nums, 0, 3), 'T', substr(b.nums, 3), b.part),
  ' ',
  '') AS AllInfoConcat,
```

Comment: I'm completely baffled. Your code works and it appears to be identical to what I had with the exception of the whitespace removal, and it's working as expected now.. Maybe my query was cached or something